# How to handle selection in reactstrap drop down list

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I have to store the cartype value by selecting drop down button

```
<Dropdown  direction="down" isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle} >
    <DropdownToggle caret outline color="info">
                    Select your Vehicle Type 
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu onChange={this.handleChange} name="carType" >
    <DropdownItem name="classic">Classic</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem name="deluxe">Deluxe</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem name="luxury">Luxury</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem name="superLuxury">Super Luxury</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem name="limousine">Limousine</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem name="exo">Exotic Cars</DropdownItem>
</DropdownMenu>
```

my `onChange` function is

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ 
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
};
```

I could't get a value when I select dropdown button. please give a hint to store the value into database

Comment: What library are you using for the dropdown? What happens when you `console.log(event)` in your `handleChange`?

Comment: I have used reactstrap for dropdown.. I didn't get anything

Comment: reactstrap does not have a prop called onChange for DropDownMenu - it does have onClick for DropDownItem though - so this is probably where you want to stick your change handler (in each one unfortunately)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the value of your dropdown with react strap:

```
<Dropdown  direction="down" isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle} >
    <DropdownToggle caret outline color="info">
                    Select your Vehicle Type 
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu name="carType" >
    <DropdownItem name="classic" value="classic" onClick={this.handleChange} >Classic</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem name="deluxe" value="deluxe" onClick={this.handleChange} >Deluxe</DropdownItem>
</DropdownMenu>
```

Changes made:

- 1. onClick is used not onChange.
  2. handleClick is reading the actual option clicked so it is on DropdownItem.
  3. You are asking for `event.target.value` but you did not have a "value" so I added it.  If you wanted to use the text from the
     DropdownItem you would use `event.target.innerText`